# GWT, MVP, GIN, code splitting?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp, gwt-gin

How to minimize the amount of code downloaded initially by GWT app user's browser?
Well, just wrap potentially big operations in a GWT.runAsync() call.
However, since our application is using GWT best practices (dependency injection, MVP pattern), it’s not as straightforward as GWT doc describes.
Could you please give me an idea on how to use code splitting in conjunction with GIN?

Answer (score 3):

Follow [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/52606) on the GWT mailing list.  Use [AsyncProvider](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/inject/client/AsyncProvider.java) as provided by the following [enhancement](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=61).

Comment: im using the GWT-Presenter
Framework.
brief the  binding is done  in this way

  bindPresenter (
          Presenter.class,
          Presenter.Display.class,
          View.class);

what should i do to optimize my code?
my binding code should it be something like this?
bind (Presenter.class). in (Singleton.class);
bind (Presenter.Display.class). toProvider (asyncProvider);

Answer (score 1):

The best idea, I think, is to use MVP framework. I worked with [mvp4g](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/), it supports code splitting out of box. It will also generate boilerplate code for you, so it's pretty simple and fast to develop advanced GWT application with it. The other is [gwt-platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/), Google invited its creator to Google IO and it looks that this framework is preffered by creators of GWT.

Comment: I already use GWT presenter but apparently it does not support code splitting
So what do you recommend?do i have to migrate the application using a different framework(gwt-platform...) if so what is the framework that requires less effort?

Comment: Gwt-presenter is a simple reference implementation of MVP. It's not a real framework. Just few classes and interfaces. It doesn't support code splitting. There's a lot of boilerplate which you'll have to write if you decide to stick to it. Gwt-platform is a gwt-presenter fork, so it should be simple to migrate.

Comment: Side note: the author of GWT-Platform (GWTP) is now working at Google... AFAIK, so is the creator of MVP4G. Both are fine frameworks. And apparently, both ease the code splitting process (in GWTP, you just have to use an annotation on the presenter).

Comment: Oh really? I think the GWT navtive MVP somewhat overlaps to GWTP or MVP4G.